# "bear witness for " VS "bear witness to"?

Tags: grammar, collocation

Is there any difference between "bear witness for Lord Jesus" and "bear witness to Lord Jesus"? These two expressions can be found on the Internet ; they look familiar, but I'm not sure whether they are interchangeable. Any ideas? :)

These are 2 examples from the Internet:
1. We bear witness by following Christ's example, by practicing the virtues He recommended. For example, a few years ago a local Presbyterian minister went out of his way to praise in a sermon a certain Catholic woman who had been very friendly to a Presbyterian neighbor, an elderly lady, who appreciated the kindness so much she told her minister about it. He told his congregation. That Catholic woman was **bearing witness to Christ**, putting our Lord's words into practice. (from Bearing Witness to Christ)

2. For St. Peter, chosen by the Lord himself, a born leader who preached with zeal, these were more than words. He dedicated his life to **bearing witness for Christ Jesus** and, in the end, died a martyr for Christ Jesus. 
   (from We are witnesses to Christ - Catholic Courier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is  ***[bear witness to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bear+witness+to)***. The preposition "for" is  a less common variant, but I think there is no difference in meaning:

> - to show by your existence that something is true -  *The survivors of this disaster bear witness to a terrible event we would like to forget.*

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bear%20witness%20to%2C%20bear%20witness%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbear%20witness%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbear%20witness%20for%3B%2Cc0) *bear witness to vs bear witness for*

Comment: And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bear+witness+to+Jesus%2Cbear+witness+for+Jesus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbear%20witness%20to%20Jesus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbear%20witness%20for%20Jesus%3B%2Cc0) for 'bear witness to Jesus' vs 'bear witness for Jesus', showing rather more variation (around 1870 - 1900). I'd say there's at least a part-difference, with at least the connotation of  'on His behalf' with the 'for' version.

Comment: The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bear) definition 9.1 fits better: 9 **bear witness  to**
Testify to:
_little is left to bear witness to the past greatness of the city_ // 

9.1 State or show one’s belief in:
_people bearing witness to Jesus_